# the first run firebase transaction after deploy - error, otherwise ok

Tags: java, transactions, firebase

When I deploy application on server (WildFly 8 - I tried my local and also Openshift). The first time firebase transaction fail (MutableData currentData is null). But next time (all time after that) it runs perfect. Even if I disconnect from firebase and connect again. Problem is really only the first time after deployment.

So where can be problem? Or is it some firebase bug?

Thanks for reply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is currently expected behavior.  If Firebase doesn't already have data cached, it may run your transaction on null, and then re-run it with the right data if it turns out null wasn't the up-to-date value of the location.

We'll likely look into changing this behavior in the future, as it often causes confusion.  The workaround is to check for and handle null explicitly.  Sorry for the inconvenience!

Comment: What I've learned is that if you check for nulls and find one, you should end the function with "return null;" rather then "return;" since that apparently aborts all future callback executions. I've also noticed that it does not matter what you set the 'applyLocally' boolean parameter to, it will still run the callback function several times. (Using javascript Firebase 2.0.2, 2.0.6 and 2.1.0)